# How to smoothly change screen brightness in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I'm new to iOS app development and I'm trying to change the screen brightness but it happens pretty abruptly. Is there a way to animate the screen brightness smoothly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set screen brightness with fade animations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15840979/how-to-set-screen-brightness-with-fade-animations)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iPhone: How can we programmatically change the brightness of the screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936999/iphone-how-can-we-programmatically-change-the-brightness-of-the-screen)

Comment: How would you change it? do you have a slider in your application that should handle it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you can set a re-occurring timer like so:

```
var timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.05, target: self, selector: #selector(self.update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

And add the update method:

```
func update() {
    UIScreen.main.brightness = UIScreen.main.brightness - CGFloat(0.1)
    if UIScreen.main.brightness == CGFloat(0.5) { // or any brightness you want.
        timer.invalidate()
    }
}
```

Just play around with the timer interval and the brightness decreasing until you find what you are looking for.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of a timer, a Swift extension:

```
  extension UIScreen {

    private static let step: CGFloat = 0.1

    static func animateBrightness(to value: CGFloat) {
        guard fabs(UIScreen.main.brightness - value) > step else { return }

        let delta = UIScreen.main.brightness > value ? -step : step

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.01) {
            UIScreen.main.brightness += delta
            animateBrightness(to: value)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Introducing a static property to a system class? Does it smell like a poor design?