# Animate UIScreen brightness

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscreen

I was trying to animate the brightness of UIScreen using,

```
[UIScreen mainscreen].brightness = 0.5
```

I looked around for ways to do it and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15840979/how-to-set-screen-brightness-with-fade-animations) thread very helpful. However, before looking at the answers in the thread, I tried updating the brightness in a while loop. Something like,

```
while (originalBrightness > 0.5) {
    originalBrightness -= 0.001;
    [UIScreen mainScreen].brightness = originalBrightness;
}
```

I have tried placing the above while loop in the AppDelegate and a viewcontroller and it "works" fine either way. We can see a general transition in the brightness of the screen. I was expecting it to be an instant drop in the brightness. Any suggestions on why this would be happening?

Comment: Because that's how the hardware works? The brightness is on a dimmer.

Comment: @matt If the brightness is on a dimmer, are there any performace trade offs between changing the brightness in a while loop vs using NStimer?